# Не запускается сервер rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

````
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch': No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:85:in `load_iseq'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:139:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:136:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:178:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:73:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:71:in `block in invoke'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'```
````

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать строку `require "bootsnap/setup"` в файле /config/boot.rb